# Auto insert individual members' names and their amounts into a message body and send as SMS to their corresponding numbers

Tags: vba, ms-access

This question is about BulkSMS Messaging. 
Sending the same message to different contacts is successful. The problem is, how can i personalized the message to send to their respective recipients.
For instance, in sending the message, i would like an access vba code to auto insert the individual members' names and their amounts into the message body and send to their corresponding numbers.

Something like this; *(Dear [NameField], your [AmountField] has been received. Thank you.)*

***Updated:***
The sSendMessage procedure below is what I call to send my messages. The way it works is like, there is a button that when clicked it populates the ttcontact textbox with MembersNumbers. The user then typed the message in the ttmessage textbox and in sending it then uses  sSendMessage procedure to send the message in the ttmessage to the contacts in the ttcontacts.
Ever since you (@ Applecore) responded to my question, I have been trying how to work around it but don’t know where to start. This time around too, there will be no ttmessage and ttcontact for the user to typed data, every info will be selected from the tblMember table and uniquely sent to their respective contacts. Can you please possibly look at my sSendMessages and check how it can be called by the sSend2Member to send the message row by row till it gets to the last record.

```
Private Sub sSendMessages()

    Dim myURL As String
    Dim sender As String
    Dim contact As String
    Dim msg As String
    Dim postData As String
    Dim winHttpReq As Object

    apikey = "xxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    sender = Me.ttSender.Value
    contact = Me.ttContact.Value
    msg = Me.ttMessage.Value


   Set winHttpReq = CreateObject("WinHttp.WinHttpRequest.5.1")

    myURL = "https://apps.mnotify.net/smsapi?key=" & apikey & "&to=" & contact & "&msg=" & msg & "&sender_id=" & sender

        postData = "key=" + apikey _
        + "&to=" + contact _
        + "&msg=" + msg _
        + "&sender_id=" + sender

    winHttpReq.Open "POST", myURL, False
    winHttpReq.SetRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    winHttpReq.send (postData)

    SendSMS = winHttpReq.ResponseText
    MsgBox SendSMS

    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you modify  your sub `sSendMessages` to accept `strNumber` (the number to send to) and `strMessage` (the message to be sent), then you can use my sub `sSend2Member` to loop through records. If you want to send to all people in tblMember then you can either create a new sub that loops all records in this table repeatedly calling `sSend2Member` with the PK, or else you can modify `sSend2Member` to open a Recordset without the "WHERE" part.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Am not good in vba, can you please translate your comment into vba  codes for me. Any where that the modification can be done for the thing to work will be okay my me

Answer (score 0):

If you have already created a procedure that sends a message (for example `sSendMessage`), you can modify it to accept the number and message. You can then have some code like this which accepts the ID field from the table of members and then calls `sSendMessage`:

```
Sub sSend2Member(lngMember As Long)
    On Error GoTo E_Handle
    Dim db As DAO.Database
    Dim rsData As DAO.Recordset
    Dim strMsg As String
    Set db = DBEngine(0)(0)
    Set rsData = db.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblMember WHERE MemberID=" & lngMember)
    If Not (rsData.BOF And rsData.EOF) Then
        strMsg = "Dear " & rsData!MemberName & ", "
        strMsg = strMsg & "your " & Format(rsData!MemberAmount, "#0.00") & " has been received. Thank you."
        Call sSendMessage(rsData!MemberNumber, strMsg)
    End If
sExit:
    On Error Resume Next
    rsData.Close
    Set rsData = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing
    Exit Sub
E_Handle:
    MsgBox Err.Description & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "sSend2Member", vbOKOnly + vbCritical, "Error: " & Err.Number
    Resume sExit
End Sub
```

If you are sending to 6 members, then you would call this procedure with each of the 6 MemberIDs.

Regards,